# How to merge two queries together with different aggregate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge two queries, they each have 3 in common columns, we will call them Market, Family, Month.

The first code tells me the aggregate sales by Market, family, month:

```
SELECT [Market]
      ,[Family]
      , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [ActualDate]), 0) AS [StartOfMonth] 
      , COUNT(*) AS [Sales]
      FROM [dbo].[SalesHistory]
      GROUP BY [Market], [Family], DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [ActualDate]), 0)
```

The second group has 4 different columns:

```
SELECT  [Market]
      ,[Family] 
      ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Month]), 0) AS [StartOfMonth] 
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'SOP 17 10'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [2017 10]
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'SOP 17 11'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [2017 11]
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'SOP 17 12'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [2017 12]
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'Budget'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [Budget]
      FROM [Harley-Davidson].[dbo].[ForecastData]
      GROUP BY [Market], [Family],DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Month]), 0)
```

I want them to be in one table that has all possible Market, Family, StartOfMonth combinations and the 5 columns with the corresponding values showing zero for null.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i've changed the tag van MySQL to SQL-server because brackes and functions DATEADD and DATEDIFF are SQL-server supported functions and not MySQL supported

Comment: I think that you are not getting an answer, because you need to show how the two tables are related.

Comment: If you are looking for a simple UNION ALL, just put the 2 queries together, UNION ALL and add some NULL columns / Converts to make sure all the right columns show with the proper data types.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't what you are looking for please give us a better explanation

```
SELECT ISNULL(m1.Market,m2.Market) 'MARKET'
        ,ISNULL(m1.Family,m2.Family) 'Family'
        ,ISNULL(m1.StartOfMonth,m2.StartOfMonth) 'StartOfMonth'
        ,m1.Sales
        ,m2.[2017 10]
        ,m2.[2017 11]
        ,m2.[2017 12]
        ,m2.Budget
From (
SELECT [Market]
      ,[Family]
      , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [ActualDate]), 0) AS [StartOfMonth] 
      , COUNT(*) AS [Sales]
      FROM [dbo].[SalesHistory]
      GROUP BY [Market], [Family], DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [ActualDate]), 0)
    ) m1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT  [Market]
      ,[Family] 
      ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Month]), 0) AS [StartOfMonth] 
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'SOP 17 10'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [2017 10]
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'SOP 17 11'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [2017 11]
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'SOP 17 12'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [2017 12]
      ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Version] = 'Budget'
         THEN CAST([Volume] AS INT) END),0) AS [Budget]
      FROM [Harley-Davidson].[dbo].[ForecastData]
      GROUP BY [Market], [Family],DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Month]), 0)
    ) m2
on m1.market = m2.market
and m1.family = m2.family
and m1.StartOfMonth = m2.StartOfMonth
```